# context.log from request function in node azure function giving warning

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, serverless

I have created Timer Trigger Azure function which calls GET Api.
But it's giving warning with request and doesn't show output

**Code**:

```
var request = require('request');

module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {

   request(<API_ENDPOINT_GET>', function (error, response, body) {

        if (error) {
            context.log(error);
        } 
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            context.log(body) 
        }
        context.done();
    });
};
```

**warning:**

Unexpected call to 'log' on the context object after function execution has completed. Please check for asynchronous calls that are not awaited or calls to 'done' made before function execution completes. Function name: TimerTrigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing async with callbacks (request). Please have a look to [this thread](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1317) for more information. So, you should convert your request to async/await pattern. Please have a look to [this article](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/http-js/) showing some alternatives you can use.